# Apache server status requests/sec

Tags: apache-2.4

Was wondering for a while now about what requests/sec actually means. Is it actual Apache processing speed cap? Or is it the actual speed at which the current traffic is being processed?

See the following image:

[image: apache status]

So as per the above, having presumably a speed of 8.94 request/sec and 21 requests being processed, does it mean that it takes 21/8.94=2.34 seconds per request? That can't be right though, since my site loads in less than half a second...

Am I interpreting this correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is completly wrong.

The numbers mean that there is an average of 8.94 requests that is coming into the server per second  since the last start of the server, so peaks don't show up there. At this very moment, the server is handling 21 requests, nearly three times the average value so I would guess you are at a peak time.